# 301 Redirect Rails 4 always goes to home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, controller

Implementing a redirect in my Rails 4 app, inside of the application controller.

I have gotten it to work on the home page, so `foo.com` will redirect to `www.foo.com`, however, if I type in the url `foo.com/about` it will just redirect back the home page `www.foo.com`.

Here is the code I am using (application_controller.rb):

```
before_filter :add_www_subdomain

def add_www_subdomain
  unless /^www/.match(request.host)
  redirect_to("#{request.protocol}www.#{request.host_with_port}",
              :status => 301)
  end
end
```

Having trouble finding documentation on this specifically for rails 4. What is the best way to go about this? I would like `foo.com/about` to redirect to `www.foo.com/about`

Comment: It's somewhat unusual to do this sort of canonical domain name redirect at the application level. If you have a server in front of your app like Apache or nginx, you might do the redirect there. This can also be handled with DNS records - check out the CNAME record.

Comment: are there any complications with doing it the way I am? I use DNSimple, however, they aren't able to redirect when I am using https

Comment: Seems like it should work fine. Definitely a little slower than catching it in an earlier layer (e.g. nginx, DNS), but that's not a big deal at all for this sort of redirect. Just figured I'd raise the point before you commit to this way of doing it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting it up like so in the application controller:

```
private

def add_www_subdomain
  unless request.host == 'www.foo.com'
    redirect_to 'https://www.foo' + request.fullpath
  end
end
```

and calling the before filter:

```
before_filter :add_www_subdomain
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `#host_with_port` with `#fullpath` and you'll be set.

```
before_filter :add_www_subdomain

def add_www_subdomain
  unless /^www/.match(request.host)
    redirect_to("#{request.protocol}www.#{request.fullpath}", status: 301)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you able to edit the answer and include the code as it should be used. It is currently returning `https://foo.comwww.foo.com/about`

Comment: This does not work it just returns www..com I have been trying to figure this out. Any suggestions would be great.